# Is there any way to replicate the --post302 option in cURL in the versions before the option was implemented?

Tags: curl

The title pretty much says it all. I'm using option `-L` to force cURL to follow redirects, but the server is converting POST to GET. `--post302` fixes it, but I don't have access to version 7.19+ where I need it. Can I replicate that behavior with another set of options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, but read further.

Longer answer: the thing is that the -L option makes curl automatically follow a HTTP redirect on 3xx responses. When a 302 is returned by a server, that used to be handled in a certain way by curl (it changes and does a GET to the next URL) as that's what most browsers do.

The reason for --post302 was then to introduce a spec-compliant way that would not change request method after the 302 but would instead send a POST to the next URL as well.

The way you *can* work-around the limitation without updating to a more modern curl version, is by not using -L and instead use a script and do the 302 and Location:-following yourself, and then do a second curl invoke on the next URL.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I was expecting to hear, but it never hurts to ask!